# filesize(): stat failed for 1658630 in

Tags: php

My code giving this error: `filesize(): stat failed for 1658630 in`

The warning be come from the following code at line 4 `$size = filesize(....);` what is the problem here and how to fix it. Can anyone can help me please ?

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        foreach ($_FILES['uploading']['name'] as $iname => $value) {
          $name = stripslashes($_FILES['uploading']['name'][$iname]);
          $size = filesize($_FILES['uploading']['size'][$iname]);
          $ext = getExtension($name);
          $ext = strtolower($ext);
          $valid_formats = explode(',', $availableFileExtensions);
          if (in_array($ext, $valid_formats)) {
             if($size < $availableUploadFileSize){
                $microtime = microtime();
                $removeMicrotime = preg_replace('/(0)\.(\d+) (\d+)/', '$3$1$2', $microtime);
                $getFilename = "image_" . $removeMicrotime . '_' . $userID . "." . $ext;
                // Change the image ame
                $tmp = $_FILES['uploading']['tmp_name'][$iname];
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp, $uploadFile . $getFilename)) {
                    
                }
             }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: `$_FILES['uploading']['size'][$iname]` is the size of the file, you are attempting to use it as the file name to fetch the filesize.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers,some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files whichare larger than 2GB.

PHP manual - stat()